# Wordpress Mobile Edition, Wordpress Mobile Pack, WPTouch - Which one and how?

Tags: wordpress, mobile-website

First of all, Happy New Year!

I am thinking about making my blog accessible and enjoyable on mobile devices (as many handsets as possible). I am using Wordpress 3.0.4.

What I've found is couple of cool plugins like **WPTouch** (for touch enabled devices), The **Wordpress Mobile Edition** and the **Wordpress Mobile Pack**.

I am wondering which one is the best to use if I can use only one.
If I can use more or (even all these three) are they compatible?

Does anyone have any experiences in this topic? If so I would much appreciate some advices or best practice links.

Happy 2011, thanks in advance,
Rob

Comment: I think this is an interesting topic, but the question probably belongs to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ instead of http://stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Free version of WP Touch PLugin for my wordpress site on [beekeeping training courses](http://www.apiculture-pour-tous.com/) but it converts my site in simple plain text on mobile devices i-e i am using slider images in my actual site but when site is opened on mobile devices then slider images disappeared and only plain text appears on mobile scree. 
WP Touch Plugin is also shows an error "you dont have permission to access this area" when you try to change settings from admin panel of your wp site with right credentials.
Then i used http://wpeasymobile.com  plugin and it is good for small sites says simple sites but it not works perfect with fully functional sites using database work etc.
I think better is to use bootstrap theme for a mobile device site.
Hope this will help you to understand.